# CPLEX: How I coding this sets expression

Tags: set, cplex

i am new to cplex and try to solve the transportation problem. Now I want to write a index set that :

```
r = customer index

Z[r] = number of sub deliveries (a request exceed truck’s capacity)

i={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10..N}

i is element of {1..z1 z1+1..z1+z2 z1+z2+1..z3 ... sum(r in R) z[r]+1..N }
```

which i element can refer to customer. Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not too sure about what you intend to do, but as far as syntax is concerned, this is fine:

```
int N=3;
range r=1..N;

int Z[r] = [2,6,18];

{int} s=union(i in r) asSet(1+sum(j in 1..i-1)Z[j]..sum(j in 1..i)Z[j]);

execute
{
writeln(s);
}
```

Comment: I have an another related question, how to return the n-th element of set r from set s ? Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi, have you had a look at the function item ? https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/opllang_quickref/topics/tlr_oplf_item.html